# ExtJS : Combobox value not loaded second time

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

This `combobox` is on popup. When I open the popup the first time, a value is present in the `combobox`. But, when I close the popup and open it again, I am not able to see the values in `combobox`.

Here is the code

```
xtype : 'combobox',                                 

store : new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    fields : ['id', 'value'],
    data   : data.splice(4, 1000),
}),

queryMode     : 'local',
valueField    : 'id',
displayField  : 'value'
```

To show popup, I am using `popup.show()`. To close it, I am using `popup.close()`. I have tried `popup.destroy()`, but didnt work

Comment: Can you post the full code for the popup please ? This does not seem to contain any errors, Except the fact that instantiating a store is not required, you can directly pass an array of objects to the `store` property

Comment: @3rgo Problem exist with in this code only , just do some hit n trial and find that if I use `data:data` everything works fine.but when i use this splice method it didnt allow me to load the combo again

Comment: i didnt post the answer as i didnt know the reason behind this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

data.splice(4, 1000) looks incorrect. if you look at the splice parameters description

`array.splice(index,howmany,item1,.....,itemX)`
index - An integer that specifies at what position to add/remove items, Use negative values to specify the position from the end of the array

howmany -  The number of items to be removed. If set to 0, no items will be removed

For your given code `data.splice(4, 1000)` you are adding any items at 4th positions, and removing 1000 items.

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp